Extract particular value from user prompt in Semantic kernel
I need your suggestions on implementing a scenario in handlebar planners.
When I get a request on a particular format, I need to override the planners that is getting created by default. Sample below.
            if (Regex.IsMatch(UserPrompt, "myregex pattern"))
            {
                plan = new HandlebarsPlan(OverrideTemplate());
            }
            else
            {
                plan = await planner.CreatePlanAsync(Kernel, UserPrompt);
            }
           plan.InvokeAsync(Kernel, []);

My OverrideTemplate Functionlooks like this.
       public string OverrideTemplate()
   {
       string template =
           @"
               {{set ""StudentDetails"" (StudentPlugin-GetStudentDetails studentId)}}
                .. other related plugin calls.
               {{concat StudentDetails ... json }}";

       return template;

   }

My prompts would be something like this.

Get the details of studentid 123
complete information of Studentid 123
studentid 123 details

I need to extract hte value 123 alone from the prompt and set it in my planner so that the kernelfunction GetStudentDetails in Student plugin gets the correct value. How can I set the studentid in my planner from teh given prompt.
When I allow the planner to create its own plan its generating as below.
Planner output:
{{!-- Step 0: Extract key values --}}
{{set "StudentId" "123"}}

{{!-- Step 1: Retrieve Sudent details --}}
{{set "studentDetails" (getstudentDetails studentId)}}

{{!-- Step 2: Print the result --}}
{{json studentDetails}}

This default planner sets the value of 123 in hte plan. How can I extract the id from the prompt and set this value in my custom template.
